# Delete from a String: All Words that Appear in a Column in Excel

Tags: excel

I've found workarounds for this problem - but I'm having a hard time imagining there isn't a simpler solution than what I have.

Let's Suppose in Column A, I have cells with the following words in them...

```
A1: Until
A2: I
A3: The
A4: Have
```

And in cell B1, I have this sentence:

```
"Until further notice, I have closed the Icecream store"
```

In cell C1, I want it to return:

```
"Further Notice, Closed Icecream Store"
```

Currently, I've been using the =SUBSTITUTE() function over and over like this:

```
=PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1, $A$1, ""), $A$2, ""),$A$3, ""), $A$4, ""))
```

However with that formula, the "I" in "Icecream" will be deleted, and the formula itself will have to become ridiculously long in order to accommodate hundreds of cells in Column A.

Another option I've found that is equally as clunky is to use the =SPLIT() function on cell B1 to separate each word of the string into it's own cell (cells C1:Z1), then using:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C1,$A$1:$A,1)),"",C1)
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,$A$1:$A,1)),"",D1)
```

etc...

In cells AA1:AZ1 to delete the unwanted words. And then finally in Cell BA1, a =CONCATENATE() formula to put all the cells back together into the desired string. This formula will also have issues with the "I" in "Icecream", so the only workaround for that I've found is putting spaces before and after each word in Column A, and adding spaces before and after the string in B1.

I'm curious if there's a better way to approach this problem that doesn't either require writing an essay long formula, or using thousands of cells and formulas to separate each word and check individually.

Thanks!

Tyler

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? You are describing what you did, but not what the ideal desired outcome is.

Comment: It is easier with the Google Sheets `REGEXREPLACE` and `JOIN` Functions if that is an option

Comment: The `REGEXREPLACE` in google sheets seems like a nice easy option. Can you elaborate on how this would be used with multiple inputs for the "regular_expression"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Google Sheets `REGEXREPLACE` and `JOIN` Functions, sample regular expression can be:

```
(?i)\b(Until|I|Have|The)\b
```

where `(?i)` is an ignore case flag, `\b` is word boundary, and `()` is a capturing group.

```
=PROPER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(B1, "(?i)\b(" & JOIN("|", A1:A4) & ")\b", "")))
```

The `Trim` function also removes extra spaces between words. 
Excel 2016 has [`TextJoin`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) Function, but no RegEx Functions yet (VBA UDF can be used instead).

Microsoft Word has similar but limited pattern matching [using wildcards](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_wildcards.html), but joining the pattern in Word would be too challenging. Sample wildcards replace pattern in Word : `<(Until|I|Have|The)>`

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. Is it possible to use this with symbols (*&%_-.' etc... ) and numbers in addition to words?

Comment: @TylerSobel-Mason ah yes, special punctuation character that are part of the RE2 syntax have to be escaped with "\" (for example "\\(" ) but should be ok for digits without escaping them. Numbers have to be converted to text, but I think the `Join` Function would take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following *UDF()*:

```
Public Function NoJunk(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim ary(), r As Range
    temp = " " & r1.Text & " "
    ReDim ary(1 To r2.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each r In r2
        ary(i) = " " & r.Text & " "
        i = i + 1
    Next r
    For i = 1 To r2.Count
        temp = Replace(temp, ary(i), " ")
    Next i

    NoJunk = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(temp)

End Function
```

For example:

[image]

Because the comparisons are case sensitive, I have included both lower case and proper case in column **A**.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=nojunk(B1,A1:A8)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

```
Macros must be enabled for this to work!
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is less then ~10 or so unique words which you know what is to be deleted, you could just copy the column, Ctrl + H and Find/Replace that word with nothing and repeat until you've removed them all.